# Adding an array of images to a collection view - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm writing a program that takes pictures and displays them in a collection view.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myImages.count
}
```

Function below is `cellForItemAt` this is where the error occurs on the `cell.imageView.image = image` line.

The error given is:

> Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'imageView'

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    let image = myImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView.image = image
    return cell
}
```

My class declaration for the collectionCell is below. It's connected to the collectionView via the storyboard etc so I'm unsure why the error occurs.

```
class collectionCell: UICollectionViewCell { 
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: According to swift code conventions, class name should start with capital letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write class name instead of UICollectionCell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! collectionCell
       let image = myImages[indexPath.row]
       cell.imageView.image = image
       return cell
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `cast` your `UICollectionViewCell` to your own type of cell (`collectionCell`):

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! collectionCell
       let image = myImages[indexPath.row]
       cell.imageView.image = image
       return cell
   }
```

The wrong part:

`... as UICollectionViewCell`

should be:

`... as! collectionCell`